# Can IIS authentication block all pages on web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, forms-authentication

I have [converted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx#Additional%20Conversion%20Options) a simple html WebSite to a Web Application.
And [enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx) forms authentication .aspx pages will require [login](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-loginpage/) now.
But the old .html pages can still be opened directly without login.
Must I convert all pages to .aspx or can I enforce login on .html pages as well?

Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".aspxFormsAuthentication" cookieless="AutoDetect" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="index.html">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please update your question with the configuration details you have tried so far? What does authorization and authentication node under system.web looks like in web.config?

Comment: If this is for the whole IIS website, have you disabled Anonymous Authentication in IIS?

Comment: ASP.NET Forms authentication is a different thing. IIS authentication can block everything.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I found something about the location element and it's path property https://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config, can this help? It's not working yet :(

Answer (score 0):

The location element didn't help.
It seems this is not possible and I indeed need to convert the pages that need login to .aspx pages.